# Solve $x^2 + 10 = 15$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, roots, quadratics

How do I solve the following equation?

$$x^2 + 10 = 15$$

Here's how I think this should be solved.
\begin{align*}
x^2 + 10 - 10 & = 15 - 10 \\
x^2 & = 15 - 10 \\
x^2 & = 5 \\
x & = \sqrt{5}
\end{align*}
I was thinking that the square root of 5 is iregular repeating 2.23606797749979 number. 2.236 multipled by itself equals 5ish.

I've also seen another equation like this:
\begin{align*}
x^2 & = 4 \\
x^2 + 4 & = 0 \\
(x - 2)(x + 2) & = 0 \\
x & = 2 \text{ or } -2
\end{align*}
So I guess I could near the end of my equation do the following:

$$x^2 + 5 = 0$$

and then go from there?

Is my first attempt at solving correct?

Comment: Going from $x^2=4$ to $x^2+4=0$ is wrong. From $x^2=4$ you can go to $x^2-4=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation should be corrected at the second line to be $$x^2 -4 = 0$$ and similarly $$x^2-5=0$$.
Then $$(x-\sqrt{5})(x+\sqrt{5})=0$$ which implies $$x=\sqrt{5}$$ or $$x=-\sqrt{5}$$
The answer being irrational doesn't matter, as $x$ is in the real number set (or can even be complex number set, a quadratic equation always have a solution in the complex number set).

Comment: Awesome thanks. I had a feeling that I was partly correct.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is there, however be aware of the fact that $x^2 = a$ is equivalent to $x = \sqrt{a}$ OR $x = -\sqrt{a}$.